# Looking for write-hardened USB with high longevity

Tags: usb, ssd, flash-drive

**Use Case**

I have an application where I need to write a lot of data continuously (several GB/day).  It needs to fit in a very small package.  It will be deployed in very remote places. It will not be easily serviceable and therefore must be reliable.  A tiny USB flash drive would be perfect, but...  USB Drives typically have a short lifespan if you are writing constantly.  Speed is not critical (normal flash write/read speeds are fine).

**Question**

My question: Does anyone make a USB thumb-drive that is designed specifically for significantly increased write longevity?  My ideal would be something like this:

- Small (no bigger than a couple inches long when sticking out of the USB port. Preferably even smaller (like a stubby drive).
- SLC NAND for basic longevity (100,000 write cycles MTTF is typical).
- Has write-leveling/spreading to keep from overwriting the same cells too often.
- Has a large section of unmapped storage cells that can get mapped in when cells fail (similar to SSD failed-cell mapping techniques).

Essentially what I'm looking for is SSD longevity tech in a small USB thumb-drive package. 
 I have tried every combination of search terms I can think of in Google and have found nothing.  Maybe it's just my Google-Fu is failing me? Does this even exist?

Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: I know it is a bit bigger, but would an external 2.5" HDD work for you? No power cable, small form factor, and you will not have to worry about it failing due to too many writes.

Comment: @CFinley - Agreed. It would be perfect! ...except it is physically too big, and my core board does not have SATA circuitry, just USB.  But you did help me here: I have updated my question to show that yes, SSD technology is what I would like, but in a small USB-thumbdrive package. Thanks!

Comment: While not a real answer, I have found a german company called [Winkom](http://www.winkom.eu/kontakt/) who have put SLC chips into their (USB3.0) sticks. Sadly their webpage is available only in German, but I'm sure they'd also be happy to tell you more about their sticks and to sell to your location.

Comment: Additionally there seemes to be a [taiwanese / russian company  Mach-Extreme Technologies](http://mx-technology.com/h5/en/contact.php) offering their "Ultra" line of sticks which also feature SLC chips.

Comment: @SEJPM - Thanks for that info, I will definitely look into them. If I get anywhere with it I will let you know.

Comment: So I'm not calling this an answer yet, but I found this company: https://www.cactus-tech.com that sells industrial-grade SLC storage devices.  No write-leveling on the USB drives though.  That seems to be non-existent. Also, they are wholesale in bulk only.  No retail.  Continuing my search...

Comment: Update: Haven't found anything yet that fits all the criteria, but I have located a small USB-to-mSata adapter that would allow me to use a proper mSata SSD (that has write-leveling and SLC chips for write-longevity).  The only problem is that it is bigger than I would have preferred, and draws significantly more current than a similarly sized USB stick.  On the other hand, I also found several companies that make SLC-based USB sticks (not just Cactus-Tech), but those don't have write-leveling.  The search continues...

Comment: @MrChips, if you're writing the data from Linux, you can use a flash-oriented filesystem such as [F2FS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F2FS) to handle the wear-leveling for you.

Comment: @Mark - Thanks! I didn't even think of that option.  I will definitely look into this in combination with a high-quality SLC USB drive.  Thanks again for this suggestion!

Comment: FWIW, I believe all Sandisk usb sticks have wear levelling, and hence in one sense, larger capacity is "write hardening". Writing 10gb per day for a year to a "512GB Ultra Fit" would only use each cell around 7 times. Thumbsuck a worst case scenario with QLC having 250 write cycles and you're looking at 34 years of writes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one says its 2" by 1.2"

**Caution 15 of 46 customers units reviewed on amazon failed.**
43% had no reported issues.  However, 46 reviews is hardly statically significant.

[https://www.amazon.com/VisionTek-512GB-Pocket-Solid-State/dp/B0185C5Y0U/ref=sr_1_69?ie=UTF8&qid=1514833350&sr=8-69&keywords=usb+slc](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0185C5Y0U)

[https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIAERZ6979320&cm_re=usb_slc-*-9SIAERZ6979320-*-Product](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIAERZ6979320&cm_re=usb_slc-_-9SIAERZ6979320-_-Product)

[image: Enterprise level USB SLC]

This is about the smallest I could find.  I could only find the 2242 standard and an adapter that is 70X25X9mm.  Maybe a smaller adapter can be found.

[image]

https://www.ebay.com/itm/USB3-0-LM-741U-TYPE-A-TO-NGFF-SSD-Enclosure-Without-Cable-for-2230-or-2242-MGFF-/263385726440?_trksid=p2385738.m4383.l4275.c10

[image: SSD adapter]

http://www.os-store.com/samsung-32gb-ngff-m-2-ssd-hdd-mz-apf0320-000-mzapf032hcfv-00000-sata-6gb-s-mlc-hard-disk-module-solid-state-drive-2242-22x42mm-laptop.html

Here's an odd ball but its SLC
[image: swiss]
https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Swissbit/SFSA064GM1AA2TO-I-NC-216-STD/?qs=Uem7cGQRk%252bo2yk0eYtq9ew%3d%3d